# Rails 3 and Twitter bootstrap's sidebar (affix) - how?

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml, ruby-on-rails-3.2, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have simple RoR 3.2 application with Twitter bootstrap 2.1.0 (i implemented it via twitter-bootstrap-rails gem). I want to integrate sidebar with few links (as you can see on twitter bootstrap page on the left side) but i can't get how to implement this (yes, i'm noob). Does anyone have solution how to do that in Rails?

My application layout:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title MyApp
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
    %meta{ :name => "viewport", :content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"  }
  %body
    %div{ :class => "wrapper" }
      = render 'layouts/navbar_template'

      %div{ :class => "container-fluid" }
        - flash.each do |key, msg|
          %div{ :class => "alert alert-#{key}" }
            %button{ :type => "button", :class => "close", "data-dismiss" =>"alert" }×
            = msg
        %div{ :class => "row-fluid" }
          %div{:class => "span10"}
            =yield
          %div{:class => "span2"}
            -# I would like to have sidebar here
```

Comment: Maybe you are having a problem with identation. The container-fluid div should be inside the wrapper one.

Comment: @MurifoX Sorry, i edited my code. It was my fault. Code is correct now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%ul.nav.nav-list.bs-docs-sidenav.affix
  %li.active
    %a{:href => "#dropdowns"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Dropdowns
  %li
    %a{:href => "#buttonGroups"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Button groups
  %li
    %a{:href => "#buttonDropdowns"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Button dropdowns
  %li
    %a{:href => "#navs"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Navs
  %li
    %a{:href => "#navbar"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Navbar
  %li
    %a{:href => "#breadcrumbs"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Breadcrumbs
  %li
    %a{:href => "#pagination"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Pagination
  %li
    %a{:href => "#labels-badges"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Labels and badges
  %li
    %a{:href => "#typography"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Typography
  %li
    %a{:href => "#thumbnails"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Thumbnails
  %li
    %a{:href => "#alerts"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Alerts
  %li
    %a{:href => "#progress"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Progress bars
  %li
    %a{:href => "#misc"}
      %i.icon-chevron-right
      Misc
```